# EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Launch crash for python app created with py2app

Tags: python, macos, crash-reports, sigabrt, py2app

I created a python macOS app with py2app but it give me EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) and won't open my app but when I try to open it from this path:

```
myapp.app/contents/macos/myapp
```

my app open correctly with a new terminal tab. I can't figure out why the app won't run correctly. this is the crash report I posted on [apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/) forums:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/710205

I can't figure out what should I do with this! any solution?

Answer (score 0):

> I got an error message:
>
> Launch error See the py2app website for debugging launch issues

*Found that the problem occurs with the program that works with the console! If you make a program with an interface, for example, tkinter, then I have no problems with generating and launching the application file on click. If anyone knows how to make a console application in the form of an app for a macbk, then please write...*

> For those who have problems working py2app - update all your libraries
> to the maximum!

**Download:**

```
pip install py2app
```

*Type the following script into the terminal to update everything to the maximum versions:*

```
for i in $(pip list -o | awk 'NR > 2 {print $1}'); do sudo pip install
-U $i; done
```

*Change to the desired directory with cd:*

```
cd Desktop/NameFolder/FolderProject
```

*!!! Make sure the required py is in your directory with the command: `ls`*

**Create a setup with:**

> py2applet --make-setup nameProject.py

*Create an alpha version, for a sanity test:*

```
python3 setup.py -A
```

**!!! Delete the appeared folders before compiling the following command.**

*Create the final program and make mom happy:*

```
python3 setup.py
```

**P.S.**

*!!! I use anaconda3. It is recommended for newcomers to download it from the official website and update the library.*

```
conda update --all
```

*If you're still having performance issues and aren't building an app file for your console application, then you haven't downloaded the required compatible fresh libraries to do so.*

> I don’t know how to solve the problem with the app’s performance for a
> console application, maybe it’s not possible to do it, the maximum
> that I got was to go inside the app file (show package contents) and
> run the .exec file in the MacOS folder.

**Example of my setup.py made thanks to py2app:**

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['project.py']
APP_NAME = 'TITLE'
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {
    'iconfile': 'icon.png', 
    'packages':['babel','pytz'],
    'argv_emulation' : True,
    'plist': {'CFBundleShortVersionString':'0.1.0'}
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    name=APP_NAME,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app']
)
```

**Thank you for your attention!**

Comment: hey @Valerij thanks for your answer.
when I try to make alpha version it said "error: option -A not recognized"
and when I try to run "python3 setup.py" it said "error: no commands supplied"
whats the problem?

Comment: And also again getting this m.f Error "EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)" when i luanche it!

Comment: hi, sorry for the long absence. Can you show your "project.py" program code for you to create the "setup.py" file? until I had time to answer specifically for your program, you can try to understand on the example of my program by downloading it on my github. 
github.com/syroiezhin
find the repository called Website-IP.
download tk-wbs-ip.py.
create your own setup.py file.
create a setup file for setup.py on your mac.
If it works, then the problem is in your "project.py" program. You should get a program like I have in a repository called WbsIP.app.
good luck, write and watch my github!

Comment: As I said earlier in my huge post, it seems to me that you are trying to make an app file for a console application, and that's why it doesn't work. I had the same problem that the app did not start, but the console Unix worked, although there was no such error. this error occurs only because you somehow do not interact correctly with the additional libraries used. perhaps you give them some parameters that cannot be processed, for example, instead of a number you give the parameter None (null). Division by zero and the like. No offense if i guessed wrong. I don't know what your code is.

Comment: Regarding your question on the apple forum: DMG is literally the APP for MAC itself, it should work smoothly on all devices. And the UNIX file, as I know, can grunt if you move it to another folder, and even more so if you move it to another device. UNIX is a console application, so it can't have an interface. I want to suggest taking a look at [this source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/understanding-the-exception-types-in-a-crash-report#EXCCRASH-SIGABRT), it talks about what kind of error it is.